# Can I use a Selector with parenthesis in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, selector, swift3

I was wondering how can I use a `Selector` in Swift 3 including a value in the parenthesis that the `func` requires.

```
let fireRecogniser = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("shootShot")))
```

^ That is the recogniser I have but the method 'shootShot' has a parameter for an `Element` which is an `enum` that I have.

**Here is the 'shootShot' function:**

```
func shootShot(type: Element) {

    let shot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(type)Shot")
    shot.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest

    shot.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2 /*playerframe*/, y: -(self.frame.height / 2) + grnd.frame.height)
    shot.setScale(1)

    shot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (shot.frame.height / 2))
    shot.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    shot.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    shot.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    shot.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    shot.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    shot.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    shot.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    shot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Contact.Shot.rawValue
    shot.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Contact.Enemy.rawValue

    self.addChild(shot)

    // THIS WILL DEPEND ON DIFFICULTY
    let spin = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 1, duration: 0.3)
    shot.run(SKAction.repeatForever(spin))
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width / 2, duration: 3.0)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    shot.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]))
}
```

As you can see, the method has an `Element` that the function requires.

Any help as to how I can include that parameter in my `Selector`?
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Type your selector like this in **Swift 3**

```
let fireRecogniser = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(shootShot(element:)))
```

Comment: Updated and fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible... if you are the one performing the selector.

There is an overload of `perform()` that has a `with:` argument. The argument you pass in the `with:` argument will be passed to the selector method.

Example:

```
// in some NSObject subclass's method
perform(#selector(myMethod), with: "Hello")

// in the same class
func myMethod(x: String) {
    print(x)
}
```

If the first line is executed, "Hello" will be printed.

However, in yor case, since you are not the performer of the selector, you can't perform the selector with the arguments you want.

You can workaround this by adding a class level variable that indicates which `Element` you want to call the method with:

```
var shotElement: Element!
```

You can set this to some value before you pass the target and action to the gesture recognizer.

Then, access it in `shootShot`:

```
let shot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(shotElement)Shot")
```

I admit this isn't the perfect workaround, but it's the most straightforward.